# Is it possible to relate the expectation values of an operator w.r.t. two different density matrices if the matrices are related up to a displacement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, density-operator, quasiprobability-distributions

I'm trying to derive a general relationship between the expectation values of two different operators with respect to some unspecified state $E_{j}(\lambda)=\mathrm{Tr}[\rho \hat{O}_{j}(\lambda)]$ (where the operators are indexed by $j$).

Using permutations under the trace and commutation relations I have gotten them in the same form up to a displacement acting on the density matrix

$\rho ' =D^{\dagger}(\mu)\rho D(\mu)$

(i.e. under the trace $\hat{O}_1=\hat{O}_2$, but acting on $\rho$ and $\rho '$, respectively).

The "new" density matrix can be written in terms of the $P$-function (after applying the displacements and a change of variables) as

$\rho ' = \int d^{2}\alpha P(\alpha+\mu)|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha |$

where the $P$-representation of the "undisplaced" density would be given with $P(\alpha)$.

My question is, given this relationship between the Glauber-Sudarshan $P$-functions (or any other useful thing you can think of), is it possible to directly write down some relationship between the expectation values? Something like

$E_{1}(\lambda)=E_{2}(f(\lambda ))g(\lambda)$

or something more general (any kind of quantitative relationship could be helpful).

Or failing that, is there a way to show that this CAN'T work?